# Python global logging

Tags: python, logging

How do I make a Logger global so that I can use it in every module I make?

Something like this in moduleA:

```
import logging
import moduleB

log = logging.getLogger('')

result = moduleB.goFigure(5)
log.info('Answer was', result)
```

With this in moduleB:

```
def goFigure(integer):
    if not isinstance(integer, int):
        log.critical('not an integer')
    else:
        return integer + 1
```

Currently, I will get an error because moduleB does not know what `log` is.  How do I get around that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could make your own logging "module" which instantiates the logger, than have all of your code import that instead. Think:

logger.py:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('')
```

codeA.py:

```
from logger import log
log.info('whatever')
```

codeB.py:

```
from logger import log
log.warn('some other thing')
```

Comment: This solution worked like a charm even with custom logger setup.

Comment: Does this work when adding logger adapters? Say I add an adapter in codeA will it be picked up in codeB?

Answer (score 9):

Creating a global logger which can be used to

1. create a new log file or
2. returns logger for a global log file.

**Create a module called called myLogger.py : This will have the log creation code**

myLogger.py:

```
import logging

def myLog(name, fname = 'myGlobalLog.log'):
'''Debug Log'''                                                                                                 
    logger = logging.getLogger(name);                                                                               
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)                                                                                  
    fhan = logging.FileHandler(fname)                                                                               
    fhan.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)                                                                                    
    logger.addHandler(fhan)                                                                                         
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')                           
    fhan.setFormatter(formatter)
    '''comment this to enable requests logger'''                                                                    
    #logger.disabled = True
    return logger
```

Now to create a new log in your module say A.py

```
from myLogger import myLog
log = myLog(__name__, 'newLog.log')
log.debug("In new log file")
```

Thus you have to pass the file name along while getting the logger.

To use the global logger in A.py:

```
from myLogger import myLog
log = myLog(__name__)
log.debug("In myGlobalLog file")
```

Need not pass the file name in this case as we gonna use the global log.

Answer (score 2):

A module has by default only access to [builtin functions](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html) and [builtin constants](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/constants.html). For all other variables, functions... you have to use the keyword `import`.

Now for your concrete example, you can import the `log`-variable of `moduleA` in `modulesB` like this:

```
from moduleA import log
```

The following would be equivalent because the [logging](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging)-module returns the same instance of the logger that was returned to `moduleA`:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('')
```

Another solution for you could be to use the default-logger of the [logging](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging) module like this:

```
logging.info("Hello")
```